# Camel properties file not found in class path

Tags: java, properties, apache-camel

I am tring to load the resource: `src/com/company/my.properties`, but it can't be found on the classpath.

#### Error

```
Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[properties:{{fromroute}}]] ->
[Choice[[When[... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: properties://%7B%7Bfromroute%7D%7D due to:
Properties file com/company/my.properties not found in classpath
```

- camel core:2.18
- camel properties read refer  : [Doc](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html)

The `my.properties` file contains a 'fromroute' key:

`fromroute=file:/a/b`

The following snippet shows how I'm trying to load the file.

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:com/company/my.properties");
context.addComponent("properties", pc);

....
  from("properties:{{fromroute}}")
....
```

Comment: For the classloader to find your properties file it should be located somewhere in src/main/resources. Or in your case src/main/resources/com/company.

Comment: @luc14n0 thanks for your feed back, I moved properties file in to class folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my.properties` file should be moved in to `src/main/resources` (not `src/com/company`)
and update the `setLocation()` path:

```
pc.setLocation("my.properties");
```

Comment: do you consider your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

For the classloader to find a resource, it needs to be located in *src/main/resources/*, e.g. in your case: *src/main/resources/com/company/my.properties*, otherwise the resource won't end up in the JAR file and its not accessible at runtime.

Dependent on the type of ClassLoader you're using to load the resource, you either need to include or exclude the package name.

For example:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my.properties");

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/company/my.properties");
```