# Properties file application.properties not found in classpath

Tags: apache-camel, program-entry-point, properties-file

I have two standalone modules that use [Camel's `Main`](https://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html). Both of them contain:

```java
main.setPropertyPlaceholderLocations( "classpath:application.properties" );
```

and I also tried:

```java
main.setPropertyPlaceholderLocations( "application.properties" );
```

If I run them from within Eclipse both work fine (having added `<project>/target` to the *Run Configurations'* *Classpath*).

If I run them from the cmd line:

```cmd
...\target> java -jar <module>.jar
```

with `target` containing both `application.properties` and `<module>.jar`, one works fine. The other results in:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
Properties file application.properties not found in classpath
```

I've seen [Q: Camel properties file not found in class path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691539/camel-properties-file-not-found-in-class-path) but my `application.properties` *is* in `src/main/resources`, and copied to `target` during `mvn package`.

#### UPDATE 1

For clarification. In my projects' POMs I use:

```xml
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>..</targetPath>  <!-- relative to target/classes -->
        </resource>
    <resources>
```

to prevent `application.properties` residing inside `<module>.jar`.

#### UPDATE 2

```java
90   [main] INFO  <module>  - Starting Camel...
182  [main] INFO  org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - Apache Camel 2.22.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
195  [main] INFO  org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - Apache Camel 2.22.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime
198  [main] INFO  org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext  - Apache Camel 2.22.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.017 seconds
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Properties file application.properties not found in classpath
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.initRouteInputs(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:382)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.prepareRouteImp(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:298)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.prepareRoute(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:270)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.route(RoutesDefinition.java:205)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.from(RoutesDefinition.java:158)
        at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.from(RouteBuilder.java:169)
        at <module>Route.configure(<module>Route.java:24)
        at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.checkInitialized(RouteBuilder.java:462)
        at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.configureRoutes(RouteBuilder.java:402)
        at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.addRoutesToCamelContext(RouteBuilder.java:383)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:1029)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:1026)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3272)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1026)
        at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.postProcessCamelContext(MainSupport.java:612)
        at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.postProcessContext(MainSupport.java:550)
        at org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:136)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:170)
        at <module>.run(<module>.java:44)
        at <module>.main(<module>.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Properties file application.properties not found in classpath
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesResolver.loadPropertiesFromClasspath(DefaultPropertiesResolver.java:112)
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesResolver.resolveProperties(DefaultPropertiesResolver.java:69)
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:207)
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:178)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(DefaultCamelContext.java:2552)
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinitionHelper.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(ProcessorDefinitionHelper.java:735)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.initRouteInputs(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:380)
        ... 20 more
204  [Camel Thread #0 - CamelHangupInterceptor] INFO  org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport$HangupInterceptor  - Received hang up - stopping the main instance.
```

Comment: Can you double check that the file are inside and in the root of the module JAR file.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Assuming you refer to `application.properties` it's not, of course, in none of them. I don't want config files to reside inside a JAR, forcing me – or my users – to unzip/edit/rezip every time a change to the runtime config needs to be applied.

Comment: Ah okay, if you want to load that file outside the classpath, then use `file:` as prefix and point to the file where its located.

Comment: @ClausIbsen The file is outside the JAR, yes, but is it really outside the classpath, the default of which is `.`, i.e. [the current directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#A1100592)? And note that it works with the classpath inside Eclipse, with `getResourceAsStream()` and in one module on the cmd line.  The real question is: Why does it work in one module but not in the other though both use the same method `setPropertyPlaceholderLocations()`?

Comment: Do you have full stacktrace?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413058/337621

Comment: If you use -jar, then the current directory is not on the classpath I think.

Comment: @GáborLipták Yes. See **UPDATE 3**.

Comment: @GáborLipták OK, "_... other user class path settings are ignored._", but  the default `.` is not a user setting via `-cp`. And note also: it works in one module.

Comment: Just start the thing in debug mode, add a breakpoint on FileNotFoundException and check the failure in your debugger. It never lies ;)

Comment: @ClausIbsen You were right. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know why one module ran while the other didn't. Apparently Camel performs lazy loading after `setPropertyPlaceholderLocations()` and since I didn't use any property of `application.properties` (yet) it didn't even try to read the file.

Now that I'm using them the previously working module fails as well. (One of the rare cases where an error leads to truth. ;)

The solution is to use:

```java
String jarPath = new File( 
    this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath() )
    .getParent();
main.setPropertyPlaceholderLocations("file:" + jarPath + "/application.properties" )
```

as commented by Claus a few hours ago, rather than:

```java
main.setPropertyPlaceholderLocations("classpath:...")
```